# How to build a map for my city from scratch

Tags: gis, postgis

Hi i wish to know how a map like google map is creeated.The requirements to accomplish such a task like building my own map from scratch for my  city.

Answer (score 6):

Well, do you want satellite or street map? I suppose you want street map, because satellite map is quite obvious (you need satellite imagery).

One of the major factors regarding your question, is whether you want only the map for display, or do you intend to use the route planning and some sort of map reports.

Whatever do you need, the start is the same. You need a map server. For start, I can recommend the [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) with Postgre + Postgis. Basically the task of the map server is to create a visual representation of the geospatial data.

Let me clarify: In the database (Postgre+Postgis) you store geodata, which consists mostly of Lines and Polygons. Both of these types are actually arrays of points along with some other properties if you need them (speed limits, direction markers for one way streets, ...).

Map server (whichever you choose in the end), takes that data and transforms it into map. To do that, you also need style descriptors, which is basically CSS for maps. It explains how to display roads, railroads, forests, rivers, ....

After you set everything up, you need an initial render. Actually it is not necessary but it is much faster to serve static images than to render from database each time. And render does just that, creates images for your map, for all the zoom levels that you need. This can be rather long job and you should be prepared for that.

At this point you decide, is static map enough for you or do you want to use it for something more (route planing, traffic reports, ...).

If static map is enough for you, you can upload generated images to a webserver, following the folder structure needed for [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or whatever you choose for displaying map data on the webpage (if that is what you need).

If you need more than a static map, then you are required to have map server active, since it is in charge of routing and rendering overlays (data that you want to overlay on map). Basically, you can create another database with traffic information, and render transparent images using map server and that database so you can overlay them over your static map and have traffic data displayed on your map.

All this is crude and basic explanation of how mapping works. Obvious first problem is where to get city data. Then it comes to filtering it, styling and creating the map. This is rather long and tedious job and I would recommend against it unless it is absolutely necessary (military or something like that). Especially since there is OpenStreetMap which is freely available, and can at least provide a jumping point for your map.

I hope I have managed to explain at least a bit of what is needed to start with a project like this.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Its Perfectly Clear.Thanks

Comment: @user2927829 It is considered polite to accept an answer or upvote, if someone has spent time to help you.